# how to extract attribute name from AttributeError python

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror

i have would to extract name from AttributeError.
i have:

```py
x = 10

try:
    x.append(20)
except AttributeError as e:
    print(f"name of Atrribute is: {e}")
```

And result:

```
name of Atrribute is: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I need 'append', Thanks!

Comment: `x = 10`  x is here an integer.
It does not have a append method. If you need append use lists as ` x =[10]`

Comment: i know, but i need get the name attribute which missing

Comment: In which context do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

For `python >= 3.10`, instances of `AttributeError` have a `name` and `obj` attribute:

```
>>> try:
...     'spam'.ham
... except AttributeError as e:
...     print(f'{e.name=}; {e.obj=}')
... 
e.name='ham'; e.obj=spam
```

**But** if you manually `raise AttributeError`, its `name` and `obj` will be `None`

---

In case you want to raise an `AttributeError` yourself, you can set the `name` and `obj` manually, e.g.

```py
class Readonly:
    def __setattr__(self, name, _=None):
        e = AttributeError(f'{type(self).__name__} instance is readonly')
        try:
            e.name, e.obj = name, self
            raise e from None
        finally:
            del e

    __delattr__ = __setattr__
```

Comment: If you want to support older versions of python, be sure to use e.g. `hasattr(e, 'name')` or `getattr(e, 'name', None)`. You can manually set `e.name` and `e.obj` yourself, even on `python < 3.10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the message at the spaces and take the last element. Then strip the `'` from this element.

```
x = 10

try:
    x.append(20)
except AttributeError as e:
    attribute_name = str(e).split()[-1].strip("'")
    print(f"name of Atrribute is: {attribute_name}")
```

The output is `name of Atrribute is: append`.

Be aware that this might break if Python decides to deliver a changed message in future versions.

Comment: is the only way?

Comment: I don't have an idea if there is an additional way. But I really wonder what that is needed for. This seems to be a critical error and rewriting the error message doesn't help you to deal with it.

Comment: it tells the user what to fix in the file I'm loading, normally it's a value, not a method.